# stacking multiple images with transparency one above another on iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I'm writing a compass that should rotate a compass image according to `CLLocation` course.

On top of that compass I'd like to display an arrow that should point into a different  direction than the compass does. To achieve that I thought I could stack multiple images one upon the other and have them rotate independently. **The arrow image should be transparent.**

**How do I stack these images and rotate them independently?**

Answer (score 1):

Put each image in its own `UIImageView`, then add an alpha on this `UIImageView`

For example,

```
UIImageView *arrow1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
arrow1.frame = self.ArrowContainerView.bounds;
[self.ArrowContainerView addSubView:arrow1];
//Add alpha
arrow1.alpha = .7;

//adding another arrow
UIImageView *arro21 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
arrow2.frame = self.ArrowContainerView.bounds;
[self.ArrowContainerView addSubView:arrow2];
//Add alpha
arrow2.alpha = .7;

//Rotating arrow 1
arrow1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.142);
//Rotating arrow 2
arrow2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.142);
```

Comment: M_PI, M_PI_2 etc are better to use than rounded off, manually entered approximations of pi.